# How to modify a list of deques?

Tags: python, object, deque

How can I modify a list of deques in python without affecting the other members in the list?
I tried deques of deques and got the same results.

```
maxTrackingObjects=10
pnts = [] #list for points
pntDeque = deque(maxlen=32) #each point is a deque

#10 points each has its deque
for x in range(0,maxTrackingObjects):  
    pnts.append(pntDeque)
    # print(pnts[x])

pnts[0].appendleft(5) #append to all members!!

for x in pnts:
    print (x)
```

**Output:**

```
deque([5], maxlen=32)
deque([5], maxlen=32)
deque([5], maxlen=32)
deque([5], maxlen=32)
deque([5], maxlen=32)
deque([5], maxlen=32)
deque([5], maxlen=32)
deque([5], maxlen=32)
deque([5], maxlen=32)
deque([5], maxlen=32)
```

Comment: change `pnts.append(pntDeque)` to `pnts.append(copy.deepcopy(pntDeque))`, (import `copy` module). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list for more info

Comment: You're appending the same `object`. Instead you should do `pnts.append(deque(maxlen=32))` which will create a new object.

Comment: Thanks, got it. This way I am not passing a reference but an actual copy of the dequeue